# OpenJFX : bundled version conflict with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, javafx, openjfx

I have a project that uses Liberica JDK 13 which includes OpenJFX out-of-the-box, no external dependencies required. The most important feature to me is that Liberica provides x86 builds too.

However, I have to compile one of the project sub-modules with Java 11, because it contains some custom FX components I want to use in Scene Builder and Scene Builder unfortunately only supports Java 11 compiled classes and below.

Here is `module-info`:

```
module foo {

    requires java.logging;
    requires java.desktop;

    requires static javafx.controls;
    requires static javafx.fxml;

    exports foo;
}
```

And compiler settings:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The first problem I don't understand is that if I use Java 11 compilation level then Maven complains that javafx modules not found:

```
[ERROR] module not found: javafx.controls
[ERROR] module not found: javafx.fxml
```

Well, why it doesn't complain about any other required modules, but only `javafx.*`? How's that possible? There is no such difference between JDK modules or...

As a workaround, I've tried to include OpenJFX as a Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

There're no compilation errors, but now Intellij complains:

```
Package `foo` reads package `javafx.scene.chart` from both `javafx.controls` and `javafx.controls`
```

because it reads `javafx.controls` from both JDK and Maven dependency.

Is any way to avoid this situation? I know that probably the simplest solution is to maintain problem module as a separate project, but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Try using a version of the JDK which does not bundle JavaFX.  Then your Maven JavaFX dependencies won't conflict with the JavaFX libraries in the JDK.

Comment: @jewelsea OpenJFX doesn't provide x86 builds so I have to use JDK with bunled javafx modules. There's no other way.

Comment: Maybe make a submodule with maven and compile this one with java 11 and then include it in parent module. Not sure if that's an option... https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: I don't understand Evan, except for ARM based PCs, almost everything is [x86 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86), openjfx downloads link to [gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) and, except the ARM SDK, those are going to be x86 distributions.  But perhaps you want a 32 bit and not a 64 bit version, for some weird reason, so perhaps why you are looking to use the Liberica JDK bundled with JavaFX?  My guess is that you are overcomplicating this and following the [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) instructions will get you what you need.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I did this before asking the question. Better than nothing.